# How to print Array from Class A in Class B in java?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first question here so sorry if I'm not doing it right.

I don't know how to show my array in another class, what should I do?

Here's my main code

```
public class Library {
  public static void app() {
        int choise;
        do {
            System.out.print("Choose option \n 1.Fill_Array \n 2. Show_Array \n 0. End \n> ");
            choise = read_N.nextInt();

            switch (choise) {
                case 1:
                    Fill.fill_base();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Show.show_base();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
            }
        } while (choise != 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome in Library_Database");
        app();
    }
}
```

My filing class

Here user giving Strings to array, filing this 2 arrays

```
  public class Fill {
    public static void fill_base() {
        System.out.println("Fill array with books title");

        for (int i = 0; i < tab_b.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print("Title nr. " + (i + 1) + " > ");
            tab_b[i] = read_S.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Category: ");
            tab_c[i] = read_S.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

My discharging class

Right now I dont know what to do.. ;/
Create object Fill fill = new Fill(); or sth else :/ I wanna use dziś class and function to show array elements in Library class.

```
public class Show {
    public static void show_base() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Fill.tab_b.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print("Title nr. " + (i + 1) + " > ");
            System.out.println(Fill.tab_b[i]);
            System.out.print("Category: ");
            System.out.println(Fill.tab_c[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you have one class used for filling the information in and a second for showing the information.
(To be honest, I do not really understand why you split up the code into to classes.)

To give you an idea on dealing with your problem: think of using the return-value of the `fill_base()` method. Instead of returning `void` you could return the list of filled arrays.
By doing so, you could e.g. get rid of the `public` modifiers of the arrays in the class `Fill`.

In the `switch`-statement in your method `app()` you could store the returned value from `fill_base()`. If `2` is entered, you could pass the stored list of arrays to the method `show_base()`.

Comment: I splited up code for classes, becouse right now I'm learning about classes. I see right now that I splited up this wrong.                                                    I forgot about telling you that my output = null in every positions, but right now I know what to do.       You're right, I shouldn't split up this code. It was stupid  I'll write this 2 metods in one Class. Thanks for feedback :)